# nlapiSendEmail returns SSS_AUTHOR_MUST_BE_EMPLOYEE from correct employee id (on Sandbox)

Tags: netsuite

in a Sandbox environment nlapiSendEmail (defined inside a suitelet) returns SSS_AUTHOR_MUST_BE_EMPLOYEE even when the sender id is correct

My distribution is Kilimanjaro, with SuiteScript 1.0. I have an administrator role, when calling nlapiSenEmail() directly from the backend model with my employee id, the email was sent to my employee profile, but not to the specified email, which is really a company distribution list. Even when I did not specify the logged customer email, a copy was sent to the logged customer email, a gmail account. The backend model operates only for the MyAccount application.  It's worth noting that in this scenario nlapiSendEmail() return value was undefined. In my experience, Netsuite is really ambiguous in its behavior returning values or just functioning in an expected way, due to the "execution context". So, with the same data I put my call inside a suitelet, and now I am having the return SSS_AUTHOR_MUST_BE_EMPLOYEE.

```
function sendEmailWithAPI(request, response) 
{
    var senderId = request.getParameter('senderId');
    var to = request.getParameter('emailTo');
    var subject = request.getParameter('subject');
    var body = request.getParameter('body');
    var cc = request.getParameter('emailCC');

    var result = {success:false, errorInfo:''};
    try
    {
        var sendingResult = nlapiSendEmail(senderId, to, subject, body, cc);
        result.success = true;
    }
    catch (errorOnMailSending)
    {
        result.returnValue = sendingResult;
        result.errorInfo = errorOnMailSending.details;
    }
    response.write(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the "problem" was that I was just working in the Sandbox, as I prepared a snippet to test email sending in production everything went right. In the sandbox you can still send emails specifying a list at the subtab "Email options"

with the option "SEND EMAIL TO (SEPARATE ADDRESSES WITH COMMAS)"

this is located at Setup > Company > Email Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

What is the record type of the senderId?  NetSuite only accepts Employee records as sender of script generated emails.  Also in Sandbox accounts, the emails are re-routed to the logged in user, specific list, or not at all.  This is actually based on the Company preference in your Sandbox account.  The reason for this is Sandbox is usually used for testing and you don't want to send test emails to actual customers.

Comment: The record type is transaction line, I just need to send an e-mail, after the logged customer have done certain actions on the data. If the customer closes a line in a sales order I want to send an e-mail "you have closed line 3 on the sales order SO34, on May 5, 2019", as memo, to avoid claims of lost data, also when some particular line has been closed, somebody from customer sevice must receive a warning e-mail, to take further actions on that sales order. Regarding the sandbox configuration, I have test accounts, to simulate real-life situations, so I want to send mails to the customer.

Comment: senderId has to be record type of Employee.  Might want to get the current user and use that as the sender of the email or make an employee record that is exclusively used as the sender of the email.  I believe there is no way for you to force sandbox to send emails to the customer email.  It will always be directed to the currently logged user or what ever email you specified in the preferences.